# Issue passing Google Analytics object to function via reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-analytics, pass-by-reference

I made a helper for my javascript in order to track some ajax events, here's a short version of what it's set up to be

```
analytics:{
        active: false,
        gaq:  null,
        init: function(gaq){
            this.active = true;
            this.gaq = gaq;
            $('a[href^=\"http://\"]').live('click', function() {
                helper.analytics.trackPageview('/outgoing/' + $(this).attr('href'));
                return true;
            });
        },
        trackPageview: function(page){
            if(this.active === false){
                return;
            }
            this.gaq.push(['_trackPageview',page]);
        }
    },
```

And I have the common google analytics setup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']); 
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
  $(document).ready( function() {
    helper.analytics.init(_gaq);
  });
</script>
```

However in the console logging `_gaq` results in an object. logging `helper.analytics.gaq` results in an array, whith new pageviews appended, but the pageview is not being tracked in google analytics.
Why isn't _gaq being passed to the helper by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the script tag, the ga snippet sets the `async` attribute to true. Therefore, it'll load independently from the body. You'll need to bind an event handler to the ga script tag's onload event. Something like so:

```
(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

 ga.onload = function(){
  herlper.analytics.init(_gaq);
 };

 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I've not tested this, but I think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any syntax errors either in Crome dev tools console or Firefox & firebug?

You've got a `'."` after the initial script tag.

Comment: no errors, sorry the '." was related to php sprintf, for filling in my params. there are no syntax errors, I can access _gaq and helper.analytics.gaq, but I expect both to be the same object, however the one in the helper is an array